# Why am I losing the game when I capture a city?

Tags: civilization-6

I was playing a single player game of civ 6 on Prince, and as soon as I captured my first city, the Defeat screen came up. As far as I could tell, nobody was anywhere close to any of the victory conditions.

If I re-load the game, I dont lose if I dont capture the city, but as soon as I do, I lose.

What am I missing that Im not allowed to capture someone elses city?

Comment: I've heard of people winning the game via culture victory capturing a city because it changed the tourist totals.  Is it possible that you knocked out a big enough city that it changed the culture victory condition enough for you to lose?

Comment: @Tofystedeth I find that rather unlikely, as it was only a 3 population city that I was capturing. Though I suppose its not impossible?

Comment: Did the city have a religion? If you were the last religious holdout, and it pushed the religion to dominant in your Civ, you can lose. There was a thread where someone lost to this after Scythia gave them 3 cities in a peace bid.

Comment: Save file says thats not the case - nobody had more than 2 religions following. Though that is interesting, maybe I need to look at the victory conditions a little better

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just happened to me too.

In my case, I triggered a religious victory for another player.

To explain, a religious victory requires all other civilizations to have more than 50% of your religion. Everyone had been "converted" except this last civilization. When I took their last city, the condition that all civilizations be "converted" came true.

Comment: It's a real flaw that the defeat screen doesn't tell you why you lost!